# Как преобразовать координаты lat lon?

Tags: python, gis

Пытаюсь сконвертировать широту и долготу. На выходе должно получиться

```
5285360.478599999
5310336.491400003
```

Но у меня получается

```
3643985.9453798616 
5539030.168736918
```

Исходные координаты

```
47,4792010000765
42,989255000241
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
import pyproj
Lat = 47.550976
Lon = 42.963041

p = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=32, ellps='WGS84')
x,y = p(Lat,Lon)
print(f"{x} {y}")
```

Comment: может я ошибаюсь, но Step 1: Inspect CRS definition to ensure proper area of use and axis order

Answer (score 0):

Arcgis хранит данные в `WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)`.

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
print(transform(Proj(init='epsg:4326'), Proj(init='epsg:3857'), x,y))
```